# Sending a POST request without submitting an HTML form

Tags: php, post

I am wondering, is it possible to send an HTTP POST in PHP without using an HTML form. Can this be done internally using PHP? If not, maybe using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. The simpler solution is to use [curl](http://php.net/curl). Also, you can just [open a socket](http://php.net/fsockopen) to the remote server and send raw HTTP request.

See [curl examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to create a POST request in PHP, this one is using bare PHP code, no external libraries required:

```
<?php
function postRequest($url, $data, $optionalHeaders = null)
{
    $params = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    ));
    if ($optionalHeaders !== null) {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optionalHeaders;
    }

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) {
        throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $errormsg");
    }
    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $errormsg");
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: could i do something like: http_request("POST","http://www.example.com/","test");

Answer (score 0):

yes. It is possible to send an HTTP POST or GET request using almost any language. I am no expert in PHP, but try looking for a method which deals with HTTPRequests and add the POST-data to a request using methods of such a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL php extension. Below you can examine the code:

```
<?php
function httpPost($url,$params){
  $postData = '';
   //create name value pairs seperated by &
   foreach($params as $k => $v)
   {
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&';
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');


$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);   

$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $output;


}

$params = array(
   "name" => "Ravishanker Kusuma",
   "age" => "32",
   "location" => "India"
);

echo httpPost("http://www.jmediatechnology.eu/script.php",$params);
?>
```

More examples here: http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/#curl-post